# How to use ag aka the_silver_search to search for directories only?

Tags: ag

I like to search for directories only, and the option `ag --list-file-types` is not helpful with that. The reason to stick to `ag` is the possibility to pick a file with `--path-to-ignore` containing patterns to ignore.

An equivalent command would be `fd --type d`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -G argument, and specify a directory name.

For example, if you wanted to search for the word "foobar" in only your Downloads directory:

```
ag -G "Downloads" foobar
```

To search inside a nested directory:

```
ag -G "Downloads/some_directory" foobar
```

To search in multiple directories:

```
ag -G "Downloads|Documents" foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list of all directories, recursively from your working directory, using `ag` in a chained command:

```bash
ag --null -g ./ | xargs -0 dirname | sort -u
```

- `--null` means each `ag` output is separated by a `\000`, which allows special characters to be handled by `xargs`
- `-g` means we only search in **filenames**, not inside the files themselves
- `./`  running in the current working directory
- `| xargs -0` - pipe all the (relative) file paths from `ag` into `xargs`, which uses `-0` to accept the `--null` output we get from `ag`
- `dirname` returns just the directory name of each file
- `sort -u`  we sort the directories returned and deduplicate them. We will have the same directory ones for every file it contains!

You can then pass the output of that list to `grep` of something fancier, like `[fzf][1]`.